# How do you change paging on GreenHopper / Jira-Agile?

Tags: jira-agile

I am using Greenhopper, want I want to be able to set the number of stories to show on the "Task Board" to ALL. currently it only shows some of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From any of the *Greenhopper* views, in the upper right corner click on **Tools** then **User Preferences**. From the pop up dialog, click on the **Task Board** tab and you can set the number of *Issues per Column* here. You can also set the number of *Issues per Page* on the **Planning Board** tab.

To always show "ALL" issues, choose a number that is beyond anything you would actually have; I use 9999 for both *Issues per Column* and *Issues per Page*.

Comment: You don't maybe know of a quicker than web way to use Jira? Maybe an app of some sorts?

Comment: p.s. your legend for answering. I just COULD NOT find it.